# Xcode unit test not work after `pod install`(LLVM Profile Error)

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

Xcode version: 13.1

I am trying to use unit test but not work well.

When before `pod install` norm unit test work well like below.

```
    import XCTest
...
>   func testPrint(){
          print("test")
    }
```

But It's not all. I use my code. so import it.

```
    import XCTest
    @testable import MY_PROJECT_NAME

>   func testPrint(){
          print("test")
    }
```

And I use lots of libraries, `pod install` or `pod update` and then,

When I run the unit test, It pending(suspend?) `Testing...` about 10~(min) and finally I got this logs

```
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Note: Profile data not written to file: already written.
LLVM Profile Error: Failed to write file : Filename not set
```

I don't know and could not find

- What `file` is written
- Where to set `Filename`

<del>I searched here but I don't know what to set.</del>

- <del>`MY_PROJECT.xcodeproj/xcshareddate/MY_PROJECT.xcscheme`</del>
- <del>`MY_PROJECT.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/MY_MAC_NAME.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist`</del>

##### What can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I used `Podfile` wrong.

#### before

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
target 'PROJECT' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  # libraries ...
    
    target 'PROJECTTests' do
      
        # ...
      end

end
```

#### after

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'PROJECT' do

  # libraries ...

end
target 'PROJECTTests' do
      
  # libraries ...
end
```